# $f : \mathbb R \to [-2,2]$ be a twice differentiable with $f(0)^2+ f'(0)^2=85$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f : \mathbb R \to [-2,2]$ be a twice differentiable with $f(0)^2+ f'(0)^2=85$.  Is it true that $\exists a \in (-4,4)$ such that $f'(a) \ne 0$ and $f(a)+f''(a)=0$ ?

I think I have to use IVT / MVT to some nicely constructed new function, but I am unable to see what. Please help.

Comment: Do you mean $(-2,2)$?

Comment: @Clayton: Well I am required to get $a$ in $(-4,4)$ , anyway if you can get $a$ in $(-2,2)$ then definitely that's in $(-4,4)$ ...

Comment: @Clayton Why $(-2, 2)$? The function $f$ is defined on all of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Arthur: Symmetry of the question (this is all I had in mind; I wasn't under the impression that $(-4,4)$ wasn't in the domain).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For every twice differentiable function $f : \bf R \rightarrow [–2, 2]$ with $(f(0))^2 + (f'(0))^2 = 85$, which of the following statements are TRUE?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3545807/for-every-twice-differentiable-function-f-bf-r-rightarrow-2-2-with-f)