# Which function satisfies $: \mathbb R → [−2, 2]$ with $((0))^ 2 + ( ′ (0))^ 2 = 85$,also $f$ is twice differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, alternative-proof

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to[−2,2]\,$ be a twice differentiable function 
>   with $$\big((0)\big)^2+\big(′(0)\big)^2=85.$$ 
>   Which of the following statements are necessarily TRUE?
>
> (A) There exist ,  ∈ ℝ, where  < , such that  is one-one on
>   the open interval (, )
>
> (B) There exists $_0\in(−4, 0),\,$ such that $|f'(_0)|\le 1$
>
> (C) $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$
>
> (D) There exists $\,\alpha\in(−4,4),\,$ such that 
>   $\,f(\alpha) + f''(\alpha)=0$ and $f'(\alpha)\ne 0$

Solution:I tried it by using the function  $f'(x)=x^3+2x+9$,as it is satisfying $((0))^
2 + (
′
(0))^
2
= 85$. On checking all the 4 options on the chosen function ,i'm getting $A,D$ as correct options.

My query is that  the chosen function is not satisfying the definition of function(**every element  of the domain has a unique image in codomain**) as $f(3)=43$ is not in $[-2,2]$.

Please provide a function which staisfies the definition in the problem.

Comment: What is the source of this question? [this version of it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2820907/f-mathbb-r-to-2-2-be-a-twice-differentiable-with-f02-f02-85) appeared a while ago.

Comment: @lulu:https://storage.googleapis.com/candidate-portal-bucket/QuestionPapers/Paper1_ENGLISH.pdf  see question 4 in maths section

Comment: Consider a function like $f(x)=\sin (\sqrt {85}\, x)$.  At least that is good enough to show that $c$ is not always true.

Comment: In addition to your function not matching the prerequisites, a function satisfying a statement is not proof that the statement is true "for every twice differentiable function".

Comment: @lulu Source is the JEE-Advanced 2018 [paper-1]

Answer (score 3):

Solution for first two. (C) is shown false by the counterexample of lulu $f(x)=\sin (\sqrt{85}x$), so that leaves (D) which has answers here: [For every twice differentiable function $f : \bf R \rightarrow [–2, 2]$ with $(f(0))^2 + (f'(0))^2 = 85$, which of the following statements are TRUE?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3545807/for-every-twice-differentiable-function-f-bf-r-rightarrow-2-2-with-f?rq=1) .

(A) True. Since $f\in C^2$, $f'\in C^1$, and $|f'(0)|^2=85 - |f(0)|^2 \ge 85 - 4 = 81>0$. So $f'(0)>9$ or $f'(0)<-9$. In either case, by continuity of $f'$, $f'(x)$ has a fixed sign on a small neighbourhood of $0$, and therefore $f$ is injective restricted to this neighbourhood.

(B) True. Suppose not. Then $|f'(x)|> 1$ on $(-4,0)$ . Then we have
$$f(0) = f(-4)+ \int_{-4}^0 f'(s)ds$$
By continuity, $f'$ has a fixed sign. If $f'<0$, then
$$ f(-4) = f(0)-\int_{-4}^0 f'(s)ds = f(0) + \int_{-4}^0 |f'(s)|ds > -2 + 4 =2 $$
contradicting the assumption on the range of $f$. Similarly, if $f'>0$, then we see that $f(-4) < -2$, which cannot happen.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function: f(x) = 2sin($\frac{\sqrt{85}x}{2}$)

P.S This question appeared in the JEE Advanced 2018 (Paper - 1)

Answer (score -1):

(A) Not true - Try for example $f(x)=\sqrt{85}$

(B) Not true - Try for example $f(x)=\sqrt{85}x$

(C) Not true - Try for example $f(x)=\sqrt{85}$

(D) Not true - Try for example $f(x)=\sqrt{85}$

Comment: The range should be in $[-2,2]$

Comment: Note that the $f(x)$ has a co-domain from $-2$ to $+2$. None of the functions you've mentioned satisfy the restriction for all real values of $x$.

Comment: (Your answer) Not true.